# Passing a Boolean object NO always results in YES

Tags: objective-c, ios7

I am trying to pass a boolean object through a selector.  However, the result is always equal to YES even when I send it NO (Xcode 5 iOS 7).

```
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(clearMessageElements:) withObject:@NO waitUntilDone:NO];


-(void)clearMessageElements:(BOOL)resetLastUpdate
```

If I put a breakpoint at the first line of clearMessageElements and then look at resetLastUpdate the result is always YES despite having passed NO in the call above.

Update:

I apprecioate the responses sent below.  However, I am still have an issue although now a little different.  boolValue will indeed interpret correctly but the method is not being called from within a notification.  So to expand:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]addObserver:self
                                            selector:@selector(clearMessageElements:)
                                                name:@"appResigning"
                                              object:@YES];


-(void)clearMessageElements:(NSNumber *)resetLastUpdate
{
    NSLog(@"%hhd",[resetLastUpdate boolValue]);
}
```

clearMessageElements now works with the original call I wrote at the top of this question but the method is not called at all with this approach when used within NSSNotification.  If, however, I remove the @YES and say replace with NIL it will execute the function.  So I know the notification is being sent but something about using @YES here is preventing it from executing the method.

Comment: You are almost certainly testing the value of the pointer (which will always be non-zero) rather than applying `boolValue` to it.

Comment: function clearly expects Object. You are sending primitive data type. You should convert boolean value to object.

Comment: Thank you for the comments and approach.  Please see my updated question as the fix isn't entirely working.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the correct approach, but `@NO` is not a `BOOL`, it is a `NSNumber` with `boolValue` of NO.

Comment: @C6Silver That is a separate question. When you use NSNotificationCenter, the method argument must be a NSNotification object (not NSNumber), and you would usually put extra data in the `userInfo` dictionary.

Answer (score 2):

Convert Bool to object like @jbandes is pointing.

```
NSNumber *value = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithBool:NO];
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(clearMessageElements:) withObject:value waitUntilDone:NO];

-(void)clearMessageElements:(id)resetLastUpdate{

BOOL myboolean = [((NSNumber *)resetLastUpdate) boolValue];


}
```